# How to call constructor from class loaded via classloader

Tags: java

I use classloader to load a class from a jar, but I get a "NoSuchMethodException" exception when trying to call the default constructor, which does exist.

The problem may to be that the loaded class is simply java.lang.Class?

How can I call the constructor?

```
Class<?> JRXlsExporter = urlClassLoader.loadClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
String classname = JRXlsExporter.getName();     //   looks good... it's net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter
Class myclass = JRXlsExporter.getClass();           // this might be a a problem, the class is java.lang.Class
Constructor constructor = myclass.getConstructor();        // throws  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Class.<init>()
```

Comment: When you call `getClass()` on an object of type `Class<?>`, then you will get `Class<Class>` and because `Class` has no default constructor, you get the error message you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JRXlsExporter` is a `Class` - you can call `getConstructor` on it:

```
Constructor constructor = JRXlsExporter.getConstructor();
```